# Postgres: - clearing space by setting jsonb columns to be empty

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with millions of rows 2 columns of which are `jsonb`.
They got flooded with data because of a bug we had in the system.

I've managed to set the values in these columns back to be empty (one is `{}`, the other is `[{}]`).

now when i run

```
select schemaname as table_schema,
    relname as table_name,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size(relid)) as total_size,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(relid)) as data_size,
from pg_catalog.pg_statio_user_tables
order by pg_total_relation_size(relid) desc,
         pg_relation_size(relid) desc
limit 10;
```

On that db, the table still shows that total size: 532 gig, data size: 812MB.

I've run a vacuum on that table and we have a weekly pg_repack that ran last night that i would have expected to have reclaimed that space.

Any ideas on what I have to do to remove the used space?

Comment: After `pg_repack` or `VACUUM (FULL)`, a table will become as small as it gets. We have too little information to tell you more...

Comment: `pg_total_relation_size` i.e `total_size` includes indexes and TOAST tables. Did you `REINDEX` table?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver - I'm using PG11, so it doesn't have a reindex concurrently, i was trying to avoid that.

Comment: `DROP INDEX, CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` an option?

Comment: interesting - i didn't even know that was an option.  thanks @AdrianKlaver